# How to find and replace all occurrences of a substring in a string?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, str-replace

I need to search a string and edit the formatting of it.

So far I can replace the first occurrence of the string, but I am unable to do so with the next occurrences of this string.

This is what I have working, sort of:

```
if(chartDataString.find("*A") == string::npos){ return;}
else{chartDataString.replace(chartDataString.find("*A"), 3,"[A]\n");}
```

If it doesn't find the string, nothing prints at all, so that's not good.

I know I need to loop through the entire string chartDataString and replace all occurrences.  I know there are a lot of similar posts to this but I don't understand  (like this [Replace substring with another substring C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643512/replace-substring-with-another-substring-c))

I've also tried to do something like this to loop over the string:

```
string toSearch = chartDataString;
string toFind = "*A:";
for (int i = 0; i<toSearch.length() - toFind.length(); i++){
   if(toSearch.substr(i, toFind.length()) == toFind){
       chartDataString.replace(chartDataString.find(toFind), 3, "[A]\n");   
   }
}
```

EDIT
taking into consideration suggestions, this in theory should work, but I don't know why it doesn't

```
size_t startPos=0;
string myString = "*A";
while(string::npos != (startPos = chartDataString.find(myString, startPos))){
    chartDataString.replace(chartDataString.find(myString, startPos), 3, "*A\n");
    startPos = startPos + myString.length();
}
```

Comment: What about using `std::regex` or `boost::regex`?

Comment: Boost has a `replace_all` function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try the following

```
const std::string s = "*A";
const std::string t = "*A\n";

std::string::size_type n = 0;
while ( ( n = chartDataString.find( s, n ) ) != std::string::npos )
{
    chartDataString.replace( n, s.size(), t );
    n += t.size();
}
```

Comment: But if string is 1MB and replaced char is found inside for 100 times, then this means mallocing 100MB just for 100bytes.

Comment: In which case, to avoid that, you would have to first count the number of occurrences of the substring in the string, then `reserve()` the string to its new final size, then you can replace the occurrences without reallocating each time.

Answer (score 11):

Use `std::regex_replace` available with C++11. This does exactly what you want and more.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace

```
std::string const result = std::regex_replace( chartDataString, std::regex( "\\*A" ), "[A]\n" );
```

Answer (score 10):

In case `boost` is available, you can use the following:

```
std::string origStr = "this string has *A and then another *A";
std::string subStringToRemove = "*A";
std::string subStringToReplace = "[A]";

boost::replace_all(origStr , subStringToRemove , subStringToReplace);
```

To perform the modification on the original string, OR

```
std::string result = boost::replace_all_copy(origStr , subStringToRemove , subStringToReplace);
```

To perform the modifications without modifying the original string.

Answer (score 4):

```
/// Returns a version of 'str' where every occurrence of
/// 'find' is substituted by 'replace'.
/// - Inspired by James Kanze.
/// - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406744/
std::string replace_all(
    const std::string & str ,   // where to work
    const std::string & find ,  // substitute 'find'
    const std::string & replace //      by 'replace'
) {
    using namespace std;
    string result;
    size_t find_len = find.size();
    size_t pos,from=0;
    while ( string::npos != ( pos=str.find(find,from) ) ) {
        result.append( str, from, pos-from );
        result.append( replace );
        from = pos + find_len;
    }
    result.append( str, from , string::npos );
    return result;
/*
    This code might be an improvement to James Kanze's
    because it uses std::string methods instead of
    general algorithms [as 'std::search()'].
*/
}

int main() {
    {
        std::string test    = "*A ... *A ... *A ...";
        std::string changed = "*A\n ... *A\n ... *A\n ...";

        assert( changed == replace_all( test, "*A", "*A\n" ) );
    }
    {
        std::string GB = "My gorila ate the banana";

        std::string gg = replace_all( GB, "gorila", "banana" );
        assert( gg ==  "My banana ate the banana" );
        gg = replace_all( gg, "banana", "gorila"  );
        assert( gg ==  "My gorila ate the gorila" );

        std::string bb = replace_all( GB, "banana", "gorila" );
        assert( gg ==  "My gorila ate the gorila" );
        bb = replace_all( bb, "gorila" , "banana" );
        assert( bb ==  "My banana ate the banana" );
    }
    {
        std::string str, res;

        str.assign( "ababaabcd" );
        res = replace_all( str, "ab", "fg");
        assert( res == "fgfgafgcd" );

        str="aaaaaaaa"; assert( 8==str.size() );
        res = replace_all( str, "aa", "a" );
        assert( res == "aaaa" );
        assert( "" == replace_all( str, "aa", "" ) );

        str = "aaaaaaa"; assert( 7==str.size() );
        res = replace_all( str, "aa", "a" );
        assert( res == "aaaa" );

        str = "..aaaaaa.."; assert( 10==str.size() );
        res = replace_all( str, "aa", "a" );
        assert( res == "..aaa.." );

        str = "baaaac"; assert( 6==str.size() );
        res = replace_all( str, "aa", "" );
        assert( res == "bc" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `find` function takes an optional second argument: the position from which to begin searching. By default this is zero.

A good position to begin searching for the next match is the position where the previous replacement was inserted, plus that replacement's length. For instance if we insert a string of length 3 at position 7, then the next `find` should begin at position 10.

If the search string happens to be a substring of the replacement, this approach will avoid an infinite loop. Imagine if you try to replace all occurrences of `log` with `analog`, but don't skip over the replacement.

Comment: How do I find out what the position of the first occurrence is?

Comment: @Sarah You are *already using* it in your example code to perform the first replacement! It is the return value of `find`.

Comment: The algorithm is something like 1. Initialize a position to zero; 2. Find the substring starting at the position. 3. If the substring is not found, you are done. Otherwise: 4. replace the substring at the position. 5. Add the length of the replacement string to the position. 6. Go back to step 2.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly awkward (and probably not too efficient) to do it in
place.  I usually use a function along the lines of:

```
std::string
replaceAll( std::string const& original, std::string const& from, std::string const& to )
{
    std::string results;
    std::string::const_iterator end = original.end();
    std::string::const_iterator current = original.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator next = std::search( current, end, from.begin(), from.end() );
    while ( next != end ) {
        results.append( current, next );
        results.append( to );
        current = next + from.size();
        next = std::search( current, end, from.begin(), from.end() );
    }
    results.append( current, next );
    return results;
}
```

Basically, you loop as long as you can find an instance of
`from`, appending the intermediate text and `to`, and advancing
to the next instance of `from`.  At the end, you append any text
after the last instance of `from`.

(If you're going to do much programming in C++, it's probably
a good idea to get used to using iterators, like the above,
rather than the special member functions of `std::string`.
Things like the above can be made to work with any of the C++
container types, and for this reason, are more idiomatic.)

Comment: I would genuinely like to use this but I don't think it works and I am not exactly sure how to make it work.  When I call replaceAll(chartDataString, "*A", "[A]\n"); nothing actually happens and I don't know enough to know how to make it work

Comment: @Sarah It works for me.  (It is, in fact, adopted from production code.)  Are you sure that `chartDataString` contains the sequence `"*A"`?  And are you looking at the return value; this function doesn't change anything in `original`, `from` or `to`?  (Generally speaking, it's a lot cleaner to use pure functions, rather than to have functions which modify existing objects.  Performance sometimes dictates otherwise, but as a general rule, prefer pure functions to mutating functions.)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a complete display of how `find`, `string::replace` and `replace` working.

There is no direct implementation of `replaceAll` in cpp.

We can tweak `replace` to perform our intent:

```
string original = "A abc abc abc A";
string test = original;
cout << endl << "Original string: " << original;  //output: A abc abc abc A

//FINDING INDEX WHERE QUERY SUBSTRING FOUND
int index = test.find("a");
cout << endl << "index: " << index; //output: 2
int outOfBoundIndex = test.find("xyz");
cout << endl << "outOfBoundIndex: " << outOfBoundIndex; //output: -1

//REPLACE SINGLE OCCURENCES
string queryString = "abc";
int queryStringLength = queryString.size();
index = test.find(queryString);
if(index > -1 && index < (test.size() - 1))
    test.replace(index, queryStringLength, "xyz");

cout << endl << endl << "first occurrence \'abc\' replaced to \'xyz\': " << test;  //output: A xyz abc abc A

//REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES
test = original;

//there is a cpp utility function to replace all occurrence of single character. It will not work for replacing all occurences of string.
replace(test.begin(), test.end(), 'a', 'X');
cout << endl << endl << "Replacing all occurences of character \'a\' with \'X\': " << test;  //output: A Xbc Xbc Xbc A
test = original;
index = test.find("abc");
while(index > -1 && index < (test.size() - 1)){
    test.replace(index, queryStringLength, "xyz");
    index = test.find("abc");
}
cout << endl << "replaceAll implementation: " << test;  //output: A xyz xyz xyz A
```

Answer (score 0):

If ever the strings you need to invert are not of the same size:

```
void Replace::replace(std::string & str, std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = str.find(s1, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        str.erase(pos, s1.length());
        str.insert(pos, s2);
        pos += s2.length();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string replaceAll(string del, string replace, string line){
   
    int len=del.length();
    string output="[Programming Error]";
    if(line.find(del)!=-1){
        do{
            output=line.replace(line.find(del),len,replace);
        }while(output.find(del)!=-1);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Here's my modified function that's working.

```
void String_ReplaceAll(std::string& s, std::string searchString, std::string replaceString) {
    if (s == "" || searchString == "") {
        return;
    }

    int sSize = searchString.size();
    std::size_t index = s.find(searchString);

    while (index != std::string::npos)
    {
        s.replace(index, sSize, replaceString);
        index = s.find(searchString);
    }
}
```