# how to replace all occurrences (in a std::string) of a specific ascii char with a unicode char

Tags: c++, string, replace, unicode

how do i replace each occurrence of a specific ascii character in a std::string with a unicode character?

im trying (using em dash as an example)

```
string mystring;
replace(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), ' ', '—'); // error: 2nd char is too wide for char
replace(mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), " ", "—"); // error: replace() does not exist
```

i could of course write a loop, but i was hoping for there to be a single standard function available for this. im aware that the modified string will be longer that the original string.

seems like a silly basic problem, but 1 hour of googling solved zilch.

Comment: Natively, C++ doesn't provide any tools for processing Unicode strings. It deals with strings on a byte-by-byte basis, which only really works for ascii. You need some Unicode library.

Comment: `std::string` really doesn't support unicode.  The underlying type is `char`, and `string` expect each element to be it's own distinct glyph, unlike unicode where multiple elements can be combined into a single glyph

Comment: "with a unicode character" - with Unicode character of what length? You should know that `C++` has unicode string literlas and you most likely familiar with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale, `codecvt` namely. So what's your problem?

Comment: @BoBTFish thanks. i will be looking into if boost has one.

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658515/4641116

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I Search/Find and Replace in a standard string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494399/how-do-i-search-find-and-replace-in-a-standard-string)

Comment: @RaymondChen thx, yes it does. however, my question is narrower and the solution also more specific. i did not find the indicated answer even though i searched quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` only knows about arbitrary `char` elements, but not what those `char`s actually represent.  It is your responsibility to decide what charset the `std::string`'s content will be encoded as, and then encode the Unicode character in that same charset.  For example, in UTF-8, `—` (U+2014 EM DASH) is 3 `char`s: `0xE2 0x80 0x94`, but in Windows-125x charsets it is only 1 `char`: `0x97`.

You can use the `std::string::find()` method to find the index of the 1-`char` ASCII character, and then use the `std::string::replace()` method to substitute in the `char`-encoded Unicode character, eg:

```cpp
string mystring = ...;
string replacement = ...; // "\xE2\x80\x94", "\x97", etc...
string::size_type pos = 0;
while ((pos = mystring.find(' ', pos)) != string::npos) {
    mystring.replace(pos, 1, replacement);
    pos += replacement.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

boost, oh yeah, does the trick

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>
...
boost::replace_all(mystring, " ", "—");
```

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/ireplace_all.html

alternatively (although verbose) using only the standard library:

```
string tmp;
std::regex_replace(back_inserter(tmp), mystring.begin(), mystring.end(), std::regex(" "), "—");
mystring = tmp;
```